# Two text labels (one for bar and one for line)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph, I want to display percentage along side the line and numbers along side the bar & also text labels above each bar. How do I achieve this?

[image]

Below is the code (R Shiny)

```
ggplot(df_leakage_subset(),aes_string(x=input$cut_selection, y="count_policies",fill="YTD_filter"))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_label_repel(aes_q(label=~(paste0(count_policies,"(",round(perc_policies/800,2),"%)"))),color="black",fill='white',size=3)+
  geom_line(aes_string(x=input$cut_selection, y="perc_policies",group="YTD_filter",color="YTD_filter"),size=1.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./8000, name="Percentage")
  )+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  xlab(input$cut_selection)+
  ylab("Number of policies")
```

As the above is coded in RShsiny I have provided below a subset of data which feeds into ggplot function

```
structure(list(Channel = c("APC", "APC", "DM", "DM", "DSF", "DSF", 
"HDFC Bank", "HDFC Bank", "TPD", "TPD"), YTD_filter = c("FY_6_2019", 
"FY_6_2020", "FY_6_2019", "FY_6_2020", "FY_6_2019", "FY_6_2020", 
"FY_6_2019", "FY_6_2020", "FY_6_2019", "FY_6_2020"), total_policies = c(2301L, 
2577L, 2849L, 2208L, 34433L, 30185L, 4481L, 15319L, 6114L, 6025L
), total_premium = c(101888149.41, 117407955.18, 164657579.4, 
115295156.56, 1452258950.86, 1571286319.33, 504515794.01, 1406433296.62, 
442228231.65, 349953011.47), count_policies = c(319L, 319L, 318L, 
318L, 3069L, 3069L, 241L, 241L, 472L, 472L), sum_premium = c(20886558.32, 
20886558.32, 16606803.14, 16606803.14, 151868936.4, 151868936.4, 
25747580.75, 25747580.75, 21809165.91, 21809165.91), perc_policies = c(0.138635375923512, 
0.123787349631354, 0.111618111618112, 0.144021739130435, 0.0891296140330497, 
0.101673016398874, 0.0537826378040616, 0.0157320973953913, 0.0771998691527642, 
0.0783402489626556), perc_premium = c(0.204994971848513, 0.177897300808778, 
0.100856597069591, 0.144037300746088, 0.104574281542604, 0.0966526180058369, 
0.0510342412580441, 0.0183070045425387, 0.0493165391739639, 0.0623202692795504
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

You can replace `input$selection` with `Channel`

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It would help to have an example of your data or something like it.

Comment: @JonSpring Updated

Comment: If you provide a ggplot example which correspond to your dataset example it will be easier. It misses YTDfilter.

Comment: @RémiCoulaud Updated, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add another geom_label_repel with the desired label value and add the y value matching the labels. Without the y value in the aes(), it takes the y value of the ggplot(aes()).

so for the % for the lines:

```
geom_label_repel(aes(y = perc_policies*8000, label=~(paste0(round(perc_policies,2),"%)")),color="black",fill='white',size=3)
```

(perc_policies*8000 because you devide your scale for second axis by 8000, so for the line and the label to not be at the bottom, you gotta scale your y-axis for those)
and for the number for the bars :

```
geom_label_repel(aes(y = count_policies, label=count_policies,color="black",fill='white',size=3)
```

since, you already have " y = "count_policies"" in your ggplot aes(), you can omit it in the second one, I just put it there for clarity.

EDIT :

repel wasn't working well for this. Was hard to differentiate which label was for what, so instead I just adjusted the y.

```
ggplot(data = df_leakage_subset(), aes(x = input$selection, y = count_policies))+
geom_bar(aes(fill=YTD_filter),stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_line(aes(y=perc_policies*8000, group=YTD_filter, color=YTD_filter),size=1.5, position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9))+
  geom_point(aes(y=perc_policies*8000),color="black", position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9))+
  geom_linerange(aes( ymin = perc_policies*8000, ymax = perc_policies*8000+100), size = 0.2, position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_label(aes(label=paste0(round(perc_policies,2),'%'), y = perc_policies*8000+100), position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9),size=3)+
  geom_label(aes(label=count_policies, y = count_policies-200), position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9),size=3)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./8000, name="Percentage")
  )+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  xlab("Channel")+
  ylab("Number of policies")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. I tried the above code for text label, doesn't seem to be working for me. It throws the following error: ``Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale``. I checked the type of ``perc_policies``, it's numeric. It would be helpful if you could paste the output graph of the code above

Comment: it's because you are using aes_string and aes_q for some reason? with aes() you don't have to put your columns in quotes and there's no error

Comment: @ravi I also noticed you didn't scale your y axis, so when testing with your data, I wasn't getting the same results as you.

Comment: @ravi updated the answer, since the label weren't showing properly

Comment: I was using ``aes_string`` as ``input$selection`` is a character. I resolved that problem using ``!!rlang::sym(input$cut_selection)`` in ``aes``. It works now, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid overlap between variables in ``geom_label``?

Comment: @Ravi what do you mean? it depends on how they overlapping? I was not seeing overlap in my result.

Comment: You can always chat directly with me if you want to show me the problem tho.